# Transfomation of one coordinate system to a another

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, transformation

I have a molecule with one coordinate system ( denote as x,y,z ) where the origin is  center of mass of the molecule. I have to define another coordinate system (p,q,r) for a local motion. (shown in the figure.) I know the unit vectors of p,q,r axises respective to x,y,z coordinates and origin of the p,q,r coordinate system respect to x,y,z. Hence know the r vector. I know the point C respect to x,y,z coordinate system. Now I want to find the coordinate of point C respect to p,q,r coordinate system. 
Appreciate very much if someone can help me to solve this problem. 
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can I use a transformation matrix for this?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\vec{r} - \vec{R}_{c\,m}\quad\mbox{( No relativistic )}
$$

Comment: What you mean by R em vector?

Comment: @user97946 $\displaystyle{\large \vec{R}_{cm}}$ is center de mass position respect of the "$\displaystyle{\large\left(x,y,z\right)}$ coordinate system".

Comment: I am not sure this is correct. both axis systems are not parallel to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the symbol $\mathbf{r}$ twice. So I'm going to use $\mathbf{v}$ to denote the origin of the $\mathbf{p}$-$\mathbf{q}$-$\mathbf{r}$ coordinate system.

The coordinates of $\mathbf{c}$ in the $\mathbf{p}$-$\mathbf{q}$-$\mathbf{r}$ coordinate system are $(\mathbf{c} -\mathbf{v})\cdot \mathbf{p}$, $(\mathbf{c} -\mathbf{v})\cdot \mathbf{q}$, $(\mathbf{c} -\mathbf{v})\cdot \mathbf{r}$.

This easy to prove: suppose $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are the desired coordinates. Then we know that 
$$
\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{v} + \alpha\mathbf{p} + \beta\mathbf{q} + \gamma\mathbf{r}
$$
and so 
$$
\alpha\mathbf{p} + \beta\mathbf{q} + \gamma\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{c} - \mathbf{v} 
$$
taking dot products with $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$, $\mathbf{r}$ in turn gives
$$
\alpha = (\mathbf{c} -\mathbf{v})\cdot \mathbf{p} \quad ; \quad
\beta  = (\mathbf{c} -\mathbf{v})\cdot \mathbf{q} \quad ; \quad
\gamma = (\mathbf{c} -\mathbf{v})\cdot \mathbf{r}.
$$

So, the short answer is that you should just calculate these three dot products. When you do it, make sure that you have expressed all the vectors ($\mathbf{c}$, $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$, $\mathbf{r}$) in the original $x$-$y$-$z$ coordinate system.

You can write this using a transformation matrix, if you want to, but I don't think it makes anything any clearer.

Comment: I am a chemist not a math person. So I am confused about the derivation. What you saying is OC = OV + CV. Now CV is respect to xyz coordinates right? I want to make sure this is correct before going further. Thanks.

Comment: Almost. Actally, $OC = OV + VC$, so $VC = OC - OV = \mathbf{c} - \mathbf{v}$. To get coordinates with respect to any coordinate system, you just take dot products with its unit axis vectors, which are $\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{q}$, $\mathbf{r}$ in our case. That's how we get $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. You don't need to understand the proof -- just calculate the dot products. In what I wrote *all* vectors should be expressed in the original $x$, $y$, $z$ coordinates.

Comment: I believe you. This make the life easy.  Do you know any reference ( book) where I can find this derivation.